# Breville BES870XL Barista Express Espresso Machine Dialing

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, grinder

I recently got Breville BES870XL Barista Express Espresso Machine. I am using fresh coffee beans. For some reason, I am not getting into the espresso range. Here is my setup:

1. Grinding level 5
2. 17 to 18gr of coffee
3. My extraction begins around 8-9 seconds and it never reaches to the espresso range.

I tried different grinding levels (lower 3 and higher 8), nothing changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tamp the grounds in the portafilter?

Comment: Yes. The tamper is leveled so it is not unbalanced.

Comment: And the grind levels, is a lower number finer? If so, have you tried the finest grind settings?

Comment: I tried number one and it only worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Old question, but I can confirm that for me as well, this machine always needs to be on the finer grind settings - 1 or 2, maybe 3.